# Rearrange a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe1` that looks like below

```
date   Name  Value
Jan 1  Jon    12
Jan 2  Jon    17
Jan 1  Adam   19
Jan 2  Adam   24
```

i want to rearrange it into

```
date   Jon  Adam
Jan 1  12    19
Jan 2  17    24
```

i tried `pd.pivottable` as follows

`results = pd.pivot_table(dataframe1, values='Value', index=['date'], columns=['Name'], fill_value=0,aggfunc=np.sum,)`

it is throwing some weird values in the `output`. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't see anything weird here.